# PDF's are not displaying with rails 6 active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been able to successfully load a PDF file but unable to view on browser and it shows as broken image.I am working with development environment.

Image uploads is working fine but the issue is with the PDF files.

In the console it shows as below;

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNWGc0Y25BNVkySnNOVGMyZUdvNGNqWnVaSGR1T1dodmFXZzVZUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVldsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW0xaGMyOXZaQ0JFYjJOMWJXVnVkSE11Y0dSbUlqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZHRZWE52YjJRbE1qQkViMk4xYldWdWRITXVjR1JtQmpzR1ZEb1JZMjl1ZEdWdWRGOTBlWEJsU1NJVVlYQndiR2xqWVhScGIyNHZjR1JtQmpzR1ZBPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA3LTEyVDA5OjI4OjI0LjAwOFoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b39997964e1c004a10f563cdc5b48a5e98386df7/masood%20Documents.pdf?content_type=application%2Fpdf&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22masood+Documents.pdf%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27masood%2520Documents.pdf" for 2.50.57.56 at 2020-07-12 09:23:36 +0000
Cannot render console from 2.50.57.56! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1

Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as PDF
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"application/pdf", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"masood Documents.pdf\"; filename*=UTF-8''masood%20Documents.pdf", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNWGc0Y25BNVkySnNOVGMyZUdvNGNqWnVaSGR1T1dodmFXZzVZUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVldsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW0xaGMyOXZaQ0JFYjJOMWJXVnVkSE11Y0dSbUlqc2dabWxzWlc1aGJXVXFQVlZVUmkwNEp5ZHRZWE52YjJRbE1qQkViMk4xYldWdWRITXVjR1JtQmpzR1ZEb1JZMjl1ZEdWdWRGOTBlWEJsU1NJVVlYQndiR2xqWVhScGIyNHZjR1JtQmpzR1ZBPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA3LTEyVDA5OjI4OjI0LjAwOFoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--b39997964e1c004a10f563cdc5b48a5e98386df7", "filename"=>"masood Documents"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 377)
```

I followed all the steps as below;

```
rails active_storage:install

rails db:migrate
```

**In the Model:**

```
has_one_attached :main_image
```

**In the Controller:**

```
params.require(:document).permit(:main_image )
```

**In the View:**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :main_image %>
    <%= form.file_field :main_image %>
</div>

<%= image_tag @document.main_image, style:"width: 100%;" %>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are using `image_tag` to render PDF file which is not possible. That is why it is showing broken image in the HTML.

If you really want to preview the PDF file, embed the service url of the file in the iframe. Here is how it can be done

```
<iframe src="<%= rails_blob_path(@document.main_image, disposition: :inline) %>" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

Let me know, if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting the error ; ActionView::Template::Error (bad URI(is not URI?): nil)

Comment: I have edited the answer by replacing service_url with rails_blob_path. Please let me know if this works

Comment: It works within the frame and I made disposition as inline, can't we display it like image without the frame and how about the same in production on heroku ?

Comment: Yes you can remove the border by setting frameBorder property to 0. I.e frameBorder="0". And it works well in heroku too.

Comment: By the way, I don't want to display the frame for the normal image, how do I implement?

Comment: You can use @document.main_image_blob.content_type to find the content type of file, if it is image then render image_tag else if it is PDF then render iframe.